# Not showing all the layout component in Android

Tags: android, scroll

This is a sample adndroid layout for my project, it seems great in portrait view, but in landscape mode its not showing all the layout component.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#696969"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="BAR 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="T"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Not" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:text="T"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:text="T"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Working" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Why" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#696969"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="BAR 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Portrait view
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlVlx.png

Landscape view
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfMVA.png

I have to use android:fillViewport="true" for expand the layout, please help me to fix this problem.

1. Show full layout in landscape mode
2. Scrolling is not working

Thanks.

Solution :)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/test"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/bar_1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="T"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/test"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/bar_1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="T"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: kindly make different layout for both oriantation

Comment: Nesting layout is bad for performance (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html). It would be better to use single RelativeLayout instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textView2 is displayed in center vertical, so it will always be in the middle of your layout.
In portrait, it draws itself over the previous text.

Why won't you use a LinearLayout with orientation vertical ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough space to place the TextViews, you can try creating a new layout with the textviews placed to the side, or put everything in a scrollview